# git: how merge an original branch into my forked repo?

Tags: git

I've a repo with a master branch

I've forked this repo

Now I nee to merge updated originale repo into my forked branch.

How to ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forked repo, let's say `git://realtebo/project.git` is your current `origin` remote, you need to add another remote, which we can call `source`

```
git remote add source git://source/project.git
```

Now you can explicitly pull from source

```
git pull source master
```

And then push to your forked origin

```
git push origin master
```

Edit accordingly to your branches name.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the original repro has the name `upstream`

```
git checkout  master
git fetch upstream
git merge -ff upstream/master
```

ff tells git to fast-forward if that is possible and not to create a merge commit

Comment: `-ff` does nothing, as it is default behavior